# Unable to launch Skype in Ubuntu 13.10 64bit - Symbol Lookup Error

Tags: 13.10, skype

I installed Skype from the Ubuntu Software Centre. I tried to launch it using the Dash. It didn't work. So, when I try to launch `skype` from the terminal, it throws the following error:

```
 skype: symbol lookup error: skype: undefined symbol:
 _ZN19QAbstractProxyModel11setItemDataERK11QModelIndexRK4QMapIi8QVariantE
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Skype throws a symbol lookup error after upgrade to 11.10](http://askubuntu.com/questions/69187/skype-throws-a-symbol-lookup-error-after-upgrade-to-11-10). Funny thing is that it's the *exact* same string and everything.

Comment: This worked to fix 14.04 also. Thank YOU!

Answer (score 10):

I fixed the skype launch and audio issue the following way:

**To run Skype from Terminal**: Point it to the i386 libraries like shown below

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/ PULSE_LATENCY_MSEC=30 /usr/bin/skype
```

**To Launch the Skype from Dash:** Edit the file '/usr/share/applications/skype.desktop'

sudo YOUR_FAVORITE_EDITOR_HERE /usr/share/applications/skype.desktop

Change this line

```
Exec=env PULSE_LATENCY_MSEC=60 skype %U
```

to

```
Exec=env PULSE_LATENCY_MSEC=30 LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/ skype %U
```

**Note:** I changed the pulse latency to 30 from 60 to make the audio work and added the LD_LIBRARY_PATH

This was reported to still work with Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Added note with relevant information from a comment made by @Terry in form of a not-an-answer.

Comment: Followed steps mentioned and it is now working. Thanks @Arun